# spark: How to get data by foreachRDD which is a DSStream created by ReceiverLauncher.launch?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka, rdd

```
// consumer data from kafka

val tmp_stream = ReceiverLauncher.launch(ssc, props, numberOfReceivers,StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)

tmp_stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.collect()
  val count = rdd.count()  // here I can get the count of datas
     // How can I get data here ?
})
```

Any idea how to complete this code to get data by `foreachRDD` from stream created by `ReceiverLauncher.launch`

Comment: LowLevelKafkaConsumer

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `getPayLoad` to get the raw `byte[]`. Something like this

```
val stream = tmp_stream.map(x => { val s = new String(x.getPayload); s })
```